# dynamic url mysql php How to

Tags: php, mysql, url, dynamic

I am building a table on a wordpress site that displays data that is sorted from one table.

What I cannot get right is to change the title to a URL, that is changeable (slug) from the same db.

The basic url stays the same only the slug changes 
ie [wwww.thesite.com/job/view/](http://wwww.thesite.com/job/view/)   --- and then the slug.

Here is my code so far.

```
function dbTEST($atts, $content = null) {

// Get all the data from the "job board" table

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wpjb_job WHERE job_country='72' ORDER BY job_title") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Job</th> <th>Company</th> </tr>";


// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // Print out the contents of each row into a table

    echo "<tr><td>"; 
#---------- I need this job_title to url link to the job_slug
    echo $row['job_title'];
    echo $row['job_slug'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['company_name'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<a href=wwww.thesite.com/job/view/".$row['job_slug'].">".$row['job_title']."</a>"
```

Comment: thank you that is what I got to work finally except i have echo '<a and not echo "<a